# Page creation not properly redirecting in Experience Manager/Tridion 2011 SP1 when using IIS Virtual Directories

Tags: experience-manager, configuration, iis7

The presentation of this site is set up in IIS using virtual directories. So an example url would be `http://somedomain/virtualDirectory/aPage.html`

When I create a new page in Experience Manager, the page is successfully created and published, but the result in the browser is an improper redirect resulting in a 404. Experience Manager is trying to view the new page as `http://somedomain/aNewPage.html` and omitting the Virtual Directory.

Could someone please point out any configuration they feel could have been missed or that I can provide to check over?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the whole of the website Publication is published out to the virtualDirectory folder (i.e.  the '`Publication URL`' is virtualDirectory), then you can map this in the `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` file (within your website's `/bin/config` folder and the Content Delivery Webservice) using a Publication element:

```
<Publication Id="95">
   <Host Domain="somedomain" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/virtualDirectory"/>
</Publication>
```

[image]

More details on this can be found in the [Mapping Publication IDs to friendly URLs page](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_7D1E9C4C050E422F92E357FC621DC99E) in the online documentation (login required).

** Caution: The following note is given in this page of the online documentation:

> Note that this functionality is only supported for the Java Content
>   Delivery Web service, not the .NET Content Delivery Web service.

Comment: Does cd_dynamic_conf influence the publication properties (would you set both)? Also I understand the path and URL settings don't have to match (e.g. a slash for the path even when the URL differs).

Comment: Hi Alvin.  Yes, you're right - the Path and URL do not have to match.  The path only influences where the content is published to on the file system.  I have recently done a project with lots of Virtual Applications/Directiories and we set it in both the Publication Properties and the cd_dynamic_conf.xml

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the issue my guess would be that the `Path` and `URL` in `Publication` is not properly configured. When a page is created in XPM the XPM redirects to the page by using the websites base address + `Publication.URL` + structure groups paths (if any) + page filename + page extension. Please check you publication properties and ensure that `Path` and `URL` are appropriately saved.